# "Could not build the application for the simulator. Error launching application on iPhone 14 Plus."

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, simulator

47

My problem is I cannot start debugging on iOS simulator for some reason. I have tried several solutions and its not working
first i wasnt having Podfile but ive solved this problem

i have tried running
sudo gem install cocoapods
pod init
pod install
flutter clean && flutter run
and its not working

here is the the problem

```
    FileSystemException(uri=org-dartlang-untranslatable-uri:dart%3Ahtml; message=StandardFileSystem only supports file:* and data:* URIs)
#0      StandardFileSystem.entityForUri (package:front_end/src/api_prototype/standard_file_system.dart:34:7)
#1      asFileUri (package:vm/kernel_front_end.dart:659:37)
#2      writeDepfile (package:vm/kernel_front_end.dart:799:21)
    <asynchronous suspension>
#3      FrontendCompiler.compile (package:frontend_server/frontend_server.dart:625:9)
    <asynchronous suspension>
#4      starter (package:frontend_server/frontend_server.dart:1451:12)
    <asynchronous suspension>
#5      main (file:///opt/s/w/ir/x/w/sdk/pkg/frontend_server/bin/frontend_server_starter.dart:10:14)
    <asynchronous suspension>
    Failed to package /Users/rashedmq/development/playground/first_app.
    Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
    note: Building targets in dependency order
    warning: Run script build phase 'Thin Binary' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
    warning: Run script build phase 'Run Script' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
    Result bundle written to path:
        /var/folders/vq/xkqtqsmx12l71dw9jj9c9wzw0000gn/T/flutter_tools.FjOdaq/flutter_ios_build_temp_dir7fPzMI/temporary_xcresult_bundle
Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 14 Plus.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to uninstall your Ios simulator in XCode and then create the same Simulator Device in my case it fixed the problem.

Comment: i have tried to do it its not working

Comment: Then try delete podfile folder in your project on the ios level and install pods again. The try it out.

Answer (score 0):

check any dart.html import is added any file

```
import 'dart:html';
```

[image]

Remove this dart.html and run flutter clean, this will solved my problem